# Parse text to json like using javascript (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a text (pure text) that has values aligned to right, and field names (keys) aligned to left.
Key and Values have a single blank space Maximum for each, and any number of spaces separating them - minimum 2 spaces.

I need to get them to a tree so I can read those fields and extract values. I don't know how to proceed and parse this text (Example below) to the json like structure.

Example Text Input:

```
Item Name 1         value 1
Item Name 2               2
Third Item Long Name  val 3 
Fourth Item     value 4
```

Desired output:

```
output = { 'ItemName1' :       'value 1',
           'ItemName2' :             '2',
           'ThirdItemLongName' : 'val 3',
           'FourthItem' :      'value 4' }
```

Edit:

I ended up using @Gueras Arnaud answer, with a small modification, becuase apparently my data has lots of blank spaces at the right.

```
var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
var newsource = "{" + source.replace(/(.+?)(?:\t+|\s{2,})(.+?)\n/g, '"$1":"$2",').replace(/,$/, '') + '}';
var jsonobjtree = JSON.parse(newsource);
for (var key in jsonobjtree) {
      if (jsonobjtree.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          jsonobjtree[key] = jsonobjtree[key].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
      }
}
```

Comment: It will be read from a txt file? There's a nice json lib converter, take a look: https://github.com/laktak/any-json

Comment: @Kautzmann I'm reading from a serial port, line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for that is regexp and the use of replace.
In this example, I try to match each line with this pattern :

```
/(.+?)(?:\t+|\s{2,})(.+?)\n
```

And insert the result to being like this : "key" : "value",
After I add `{` and `}` around the string result.
And to obtain an object I use `JSON.parse()`

```js
var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
var newsource = "{" + source.replace(/(.+?)(?:\t+|\s{2,})(.+?)\n/g, '"$1":"$2",').replace(/,$/, '') + '}';
var obj = JSON.parse(newsource);


document.getElementById('source').value = newsource;
```

```html
<textarea id="source" rows="10" cols="100">
Item Name 1         value 1
Item Name 2               2
Third Item Long Name  val 3 
Fourth Item         value 4
</textarea>
```

---